# Problema con GRUP BY mas condiciones Where

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy aquí porque tengo una duda en sql , al utilizar `GROUP BY` + Condición `WHERE`,  me da error,tengo un a tabla de menús diarios que me interesa saber cual son los platos mas elegidos, y además, me interesa saber el día, ya que el menú diario cambia diariamente. Muchas Gracias

Consulta

```
SELECT Primers,count(Primers) 
FROM `menus` 
GROUP BY Primers 
WHERE Data_pedido = '2020-09-09'
```

Tabla Que quiero hacer la consulta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Luke si la columna fuera calculada claro que sí, el problema es la ubicación del `where`

Comment: El GROUP BY va despues del WHERE

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un error en tu consulta, la cláusula `WHERE` va antes del `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Primers,count(Primers) 
FROM `menus` 
WHERE Data_pedido = '2020-09-09'
GROUP BY Primers
```

Si lo que quieres es ver la cuenta por días, agrupalo por días

```
SELECT Data_pedido, Primers, count(Primers) 
FROM `menus` 
GROUP BY Data_pedido, Primers
```

Si solo quieres que por cada día aparezca el primer plato que más se pidió podemos recurrir a una subconsulta.

```
SELECT Data_pedido, Primers, MAX(Primers)
FROM (
    SELECT Data_pedido, Primers, count(Primers) as Primers
    FROM `menus` 
    GROUP BY Data_pedido, Primers 
) as a
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Roger Torne